# Change shortcut for "scroll down one page?"

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

The keyboard shortcut in MacOS to scroll down one page is currently fn + down arrow. Is there any way to assign option + down arrow to that function?

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to be possible. Opt/arrow **does** scroll by a page, but only when you are not focussed in a text area, or in Finder. In text areas, it becomes a cursor move, in Finder it's 'step through folder history.'